# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment (ant and ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, fatal-error

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 11 source files to /u1/g24zhu/cs349/g24zhu/A1/out
    [javac] Note: /u1/g24zhu/cs349/g24zhu/A1/src/Model.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

run:
     [java] #
     [java] # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
     [java] #
     [java] #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f10f81b2009, pid=187893, tid=187894
     [java] #
     [java] # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
     [java] # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
     [java] # Problematic frame:
     [java] # C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
     [java] #
     [java] # No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
     [java] #
     [java] # An error report file with more information is saved as:
     [java] # /u1/g24zhu/cs349/g24zhu/A1/hs_err_pid187893.log
     [java] #
     [java] # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
     [java] #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
     [java] # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
     [java] # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
     [java] #
     [java] Java Result: 134

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

So I tried to "ant" a java project in ubuntu environment and gives me this error but it runs perfectly fine in Eclipse.
What could be the reason?

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
Edit:
Here is a part of the error file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f94e2df6009, pid=29300, tid=29301
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: /u1/g24zhu/cs349/g24zhu/A1/core
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: Main

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697A v4 @ 2.60GHz, 64 cores, 251G, Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Time: Fri Jul 21 19:49:31 2017 EDT elapsed time: 2 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f94dc00f000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=29301, stack(0x00007f94e5b4a000,0x00007f94e5c4b000)]

Stack: [0x00007f94e5b4a000,0x00007f94e5c4b000],  sp=0x00007f94e5c47750,  free space=1013k Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C  [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19 C  [libfontmanager.so+0x33f8e] C [libfreetype.so.6+0x14d2b]  FT_Stream_Seek+0x1b

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) j  sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.initNativeScaler(Lsun/font/Font2D;IIZI)J+0 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.<init>(Lsun/font/Font2D;IZI)V+26 java.desktop@9-internal v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0 java.base@9-internal j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85 java.base@9-internal j  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5 java.base@9-internal j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+65 java.base@9-internal j  sun.font.FontScaler.getScaler(Lsun/font/Font2D;IZI)Lsun/font/FontScaler;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.TrueTypeFont.getScaler()Lsun/font/FontScaler;+21 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.<init>(Lsun/font/FileFont;Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)V+204 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.FileFont.createStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+18 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;Z)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+92 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.Font2D.getStrike(Lsun/font/FontStrikeDesc;)Lsun/font/FontStrike;+3 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(I)Lsun/font/PhysicalStrike;+23 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics()Lsun/font/StrikeMetrics;+31 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics()V+28 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)V+62 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)Lsun/font/FontDesignMetrics;+128 java.desktop@9-internal j  sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+15 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+2 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLabelUI.getPreferredSize(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+144 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+26 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.GridLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+88 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+264 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.GridLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+88 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.CardLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+44 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+157 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+26 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+39 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Ljava/awt/Container;)Ljava/awt/Dimension;+157 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.preferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+43 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize()Ljava/awt/Dimension;+1 java.desktop@9-internal j  java.awt.Window.pack()V+32 java.desktop@9-internal j  GameView.<init>(LModel;LController;)V+1198 j  Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+28 v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value RDX=0x0000000000010002 is an unknown value RSP=0x00007f94e5c47750 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f94dc00f000 RBP=0x00007f94e5c47760 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f94dc00f000 RSI=0x0000000000010002 is an unknown value RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R10=0x00000000000001db is an unknown value R11=0x00007f94e2df5ff0: JNU_GetEnv+0x0000000000000000 in /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib/amd64/libjava.so at 0x00007f94e2dd9000 R12=0x00007f94dc96d920 is an unknown value R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value R15=0x00007f94dc972630 is an unknown value


Registers: RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000010002 RSP=0x00007f94e5c47750, RBP=0x00007f94e5c47760, RSI=0x0000000000010002, RDI=0x0000000000000000 R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x00000000000001db, R11=0x00007f94e2df5ff0 R12=0x00007f94dc96d920, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00007f94dc972630 RIP=0x00007f94e2df6009, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004   TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f94e5c47750) 0x00007f94e5c47750:   0000000000000000 e4984e0afa3e0100 0x00007f94e5c47760:   00007f94e5c477a0 00007f925e283f8e 0x00007f94e5c47770:   00007f94dc971aa0 00007f94dc96d920 0x00007f94e5c47780:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x00007f94e5c47790:   00007f94dc96d920 00007f94dc972630 0x00007f94e5c477a0:   0000000000000000 00007f925dfbad2b 0x00007f94e5c477b0:   0000000000000000 00007f925e24cd80 0x00007f94e5c477c0:   0000000000000000 00007f925dfce8e0 0x00007f94e5c477d0:   0000000000000002 0000003200000008 0x00007f94e5c477e0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x00007f94e5c477f0:   0000006e0000005b 0000000000000000 0x00007f94e5c47800:   0000000000000000 0000007c00000077 0x00007f94e5c47810:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x00007f94e5c47820:   000000004e8b41d0 468b41e04e8b45e8 0x00007f94e5c47830:   0000000000000000 00007f94dc000020 0x00007f94e5c47840:   0000000000000070 00007f94e5c478f4 0x00007f94e5c47850:   00007f94dc971aa0 00007f94dc972630 0x00007f94e5c47860:   00007f94e5c478f4 00007f94e550d184 0x00007f94e5c47870:   00007f94e5c479c0 00007f94e5c478a4 0x00007f94e5c47880:   00007f925e2499e0 e4984e0afa3e0100 0x00007f94e5c47890:   0000000000000070 00007f94dc96d9e0 0x00007f94e5c478a0:   00007f925e2499e0 00007f94e5c479b8 0x00007f94e5c478b0:   00007f94dc971aa0 00007f94dc972630 0x00007f94e5c478c0:   00007f94dc972b60 00007f925dfbd4c2 0x00007f94e5c478d0:   0000000100000000 00007f94e5c479c0 0x00007f94e5c478e0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x00007f94e5c478f0:   00000000e5c479b8 e4984e0afa3e0100 0x00007f94e5c47900:   00007f94dc96d9e0 00007f94e5c479c0 0x00007f94e5c47910:   0000000000000000 00007f94dc9719c8 0x00007f94e5c47920:   00007f94e5c47bc0 00007f94dc971928 0x00007f94e5c47930:   00007f94dc971aa0 00007f925dfbf581 0x00007f94e5c47940:   00007f94e5c479c0 00007f925dfbf376 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f94e2df6009) 0x00007f94e2df5fe9:   ff eb ea 0f 1f 40 00 55 89 f2 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 0x00007f94e2df5ff9:   10 64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 45 f8 31 c0 0x00007f94e2df6009:   48 8b 07 48 8d 75 f0 ff 50 30 48 8b 4d f8 64 48 0x00007f94e2df6019:   33 0c 25 28 00 00 00 48 8b 45 f0 75 02 c9 c3 e8 


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )   0x00007f9254003800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=29488, stack(0x00007f925d26c000,0x00007f925d36d000)]   0x00007f9254002000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=29487, stack(0x00007f925d36d000,0x00007f925d46e000)]   0x00007f94dc936000 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29486, stack(0x00007f925d66e000,0x00007f925d76f000)]   0x00007f94dc8ee800 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=29479, stack(0x00007f925d76f000,0x00007f925d870000)]   0x00007f94dc8d4000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29472, stack(0x00007f925dc80000,0x00007f925dd81000)]   0x00007f94dc839800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29439, stack(0x00007f92cc13c000,0x00007f92cc23d000)]   0x00007f94dc793800 JavaThread "Common-Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29437, stack(0x00007f92cc23d000,0x00007f92cc33e000)]   0x00007f94dc784000 JavaThread "Sweeper thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29435, stack(0x00007f92cc768000,0x00007f92cc869000)]   0x00007f94dc782800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29434, stack(0x00007f92cc869000,0x00007f92cc96a000)]   0x00007f94dc781000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29433, stack(0x00007f92cc96a000,0x00007f92cca6b000)]   0x00007f94dc77f000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29432, stack(0x00007f92cca6b000,0x00007f92ccb6c000)]   0x00007f94dc77d800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29431, stack(0x00007f92ccb6c000,0x00007f92ccc6d000)]   0x00007f94dc77b800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29430, stack(0x00007f92ccc6d000,0x00007f92ccd6e000)]   0x00007f94dc779800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29429, stack(0x00007f92ccd6e000,0x00007f92cce6f000)]   0x00007f94dc777800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29428, stack(0x00007f92cce6f000,0x00007f92ccf70000)]   0x00007f94dc775800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29427, stack(0x00007f92ccf70000,0x00007f92cd071000)]   0x00007f94dc774000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29426, stack(0x00007f92cd071000,0x00007f92cd172000)]   0x00007f94dc772000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29425, stack(0x00007f92cd172000,0x00007f92cd273000)]   0x00007f94dc770000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29424, stack(0x00007f92cd273000,0x00007f92cd374000)]   0x00007f94dc76e000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29423, stack(0x00007f92cd374000,0x00007f92cd475000)]   0x00007f94dc76c000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29422, stack(0x00007f92cd475000,0x00007f92cd576000)]   0x00007f94dc76a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29421, stack(0x00007f92cd576000,0x00007f92cd677000)]   0x00007f94dc768000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29420, stack(0x00007f92cd677000,0x00007f92cd778000)]   0x00007f94dc766800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29419, stack(0x00007f92cd778000,0x00007f92cd879000)]   0x00007f94dc764800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=29417, stack(0x00007f92cd879000,0x00007f92cd97a000)]   0x00007f94dc760800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=29416, stack(0x00007f92cd97a000,0x00007f92cda7b000)]   0x00007f94dc75e800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29415, stack(0x00007f92cda7b000,0x00007f92cdb7c000)]   0x00007f94dc75c800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29414, stack(0x00007f92cdb7c000,0x00007f92cdc7d000)]   0x00007f94dc74b800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29413, stack(0x00007f92cdc7d000,0x00007f92cdd7e000)]   0x00007f94dc747800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29412, stack(0x00007f92cdd7e000,0x00007f92cde7f000)]
=>0x00007f94dc00f000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=29301, stack(0x00007f94e5b4a000,0x00007f94e5c4b000)]

Other Threads:   0x00007f94dc73d800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f92cde7f000,0x00007f92cdf80000] [id=29410]   0x00007f94dc83c000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f92cc03b000,0x00007f92cc13c000] [id=29440]
```

Comment: what's in that error report file?

Comment: @Elliott Just updated

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very early (more than a year old) Early-Access version of [Java 9, which has not yet been released](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/). Your problem seems to be related to this Java 9 Early-Access version. **[Use Java 8 instead](https://askubuntu.com/a/791039)**. Probably, you use a different and stable Java version in Eclipse (see *Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Configuration*).